# Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG) return null

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am trying to do a NFC reader app, but when I call:
`Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);` in onNewIntent method null is returned, that is my MainActivity code:

```
public class LectorNFC extends AppCompatActivity {
    static private ArrayList<TagWrapper> tags = new ArrayList<TagWrapper>();
    static private int currentTagIndex = -1;

    private NfcAdapter adapter = null;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;

    private TextView currentTagView;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    private float touchDownX, touchUpX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lector_nfc);

        currentTagView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentTagView);
        currentTagView.setText("Loading...");

        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandableListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final float swipeThreshold = 150;

                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        touchDownX = event.getX();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        touchUpX = event.getX();
                        final float deltaX = touchUpX - touchDownX;

                        if (deltaX > swipeThreshold) {
                            showPreviousTag();
                        } else if (deltaX < -swipeThreshold) {
                            showNextTag();
                        }

                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            Utils.showNfcSettingsDialog(this);
            return;
        }

        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            currentTagView.setText("Scan a tag");
        }

        showTag();

        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d("onNewIntent", "Discovered tag with intent " + intent);

        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        String tagId;
        if(tag != null) tagId = Utils.bytesToHex(tag.getId());
        else tagId = Utils.bytesToHex(null);

        TagWrapper tagWrapper = new TagWrapper(tagId);

        ArrayList<String> misc = new ArrayList<String>();
        misc.add("scanned at: " + Utils.now());

        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

        String tagData = "";

        if (rawMsgs != null) {

            NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
            NdefRecord cardRecord = msg.getRecords()[0];
            try {
                tagData = readRecord(cardRecord.getPayload());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e("TagScan", e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }

        misc.add("tag data: " + tagData);
        tagWrapper.techList.put("Misc", misc);

        if(tag != null){
            for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
                tech = tech.replace("android.nfc.tech.", "");
                List<String> info = getTagInfo(tag, tech);
                tagWrapper.techList.put("Technology: " + tech, info);
            }
        }

        if (tags.size() == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe right to see previous tags", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        tags.add(tagWrapper);
        currentTagIndex = tags.size() - 1;
        showTag();
    }
```

And this is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.QRGen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".LectorNFC"
            android:exported="false">
        </activity>
```

My hipotesis is that the intent that is used in onNewIntent is not the correct one, but I am new to Android Studio so don´t really know how to solve this.

I tryed to include intent-filter in the manifest to filter the kind of intents that my app detects, but didn´t work, I also tryed to add `setIntent(intent);` below `super.onNewIntent(intent);` in onNewIntent, but it didn't work either.